# Syntax highlighting copying "non-breaking spaces" in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

For whatever reason, VSCode is copying [non-breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), when I copy/paste code with syntax highlighting. This is no problem as long as I work inside VSCode, but it's a nightmare when copy/pasting stuff in and out of VSCode.

I'm using MSWord with the "hidden characters" feature activated as an easy means to understand what is happening. I can reproduce it like this:

1. Create a new file (no extension, not saved) in VSCode, type some text, select
   all and copy/paste in MSWord -> spaces are **normal U+0020 spaces**,
   NO syntax highlighting was copied.
2. Save the file as a ".txt" file, select all and copy/paste in MSWord -> spaces are **normal U+0020 spaces**, NO syntax highlighting was copied.
3. Save as a python file ".py" (or Markdown, or HTML...), select all and copy/paste in MSWord -> spaces are **non-breaking-spaces U+00A0 spaces**, syntax highlighting was copied.
4. Save as a text file ".txt", select all and copy/paste in MSWord -> spaces are **non-breaking-spaces U+00A0 spaces**, syntax highlighting was copied.

Since a picture is better than 1000 words, here's the output from MSWord:
[image: Scenarios output in Word]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that VSCode copy styled or unstyled content into the clipboard depending on the context. That may cause trouble when pasting into some kind of rich text editor.

In the settings JSON file add `editor.copyWithSyntaxHighlighting` set to `false` in order to disable this behaviour for good.

Note that there is still a separate command `Copy With Syntax Highlighting` in the pallete which you can bind to some other keys in case you need it. This one does not affected by the option above.

Refer to this PR https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/54155